# Entity Framework Core 3.1.3 very slow first query used within AWS Lambda Function(s) and AWS API Gateway serverless API

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway which proxies to several AWS Lambda Functions. These functions read and write from a PostgreSQL database (AWS Aurora PostgreSQL). I have wired up the data access using Entity Framework Core Database First. I have an issue where the first time after a few minutes that I call my API, and the Lambda function executes, the first query via EF Core to the database takes up to 29 seconds(!). The next one, executed only a second later, will take only 200ms.

I know what you're thinking, it's Lambda cold starts. Well, I have kind of ruled that out, because if I take out any of the EF Core code, and just let my function return a dummy response, the time goes down to about 4 seconds response, then 200ms if I invoke again a second later.

If I examine the log for my function, I can also see that the latency is at the point when the first EF Core query is executed, other events prior to that occur quite quickly. See below excerpt.

"Found test customer" is the first return of data from the database from a query. See excerpt below:

```
            using (var loyalty = new loyaltyContext())
            {
                var testArray = new string[]
                    {Customer.CustomerStateReasonCodes.Deceased, 
                        Customer.CustomerStateReasonCodes.Fraud};

                var dupeEmailCustomers = (from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
                        where c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
                        join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
                        where cu.Status == Customer.CustomerStates.Active
                        select c).AsNoTracking()
                    .Union(from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
                        where c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
                        join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
                        where cu.Status != Customer.CustomerStates.Active &&
                              testArray.Contains(cu.StatusReason)
                        select c).AsNoTracking();

                foreach (var cust in dupeEmailCustomers)
                {
                    context.Logger.LogLine($"Found test customer {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust)}");
                }
            }
```

Here's the Lambda execution log:

[image]

Notice the jump from 9:26secs to 9:44secs. That's the trip to the database and back. Now if I invoke the same API again straight afterwards, it happens sub-second. I am assuming this is EF Core. My issue is that I am unsure within the architecture of AWS Lambda, how I might be able to decrease this first query latency. I have enabled provisioned concurrency for AWS Lambda which supposedly keeps instances of the containers containing my code 'warm' and ready to run, but it has made no difference.

I suspect this is because the only part of the Lambda code that's kept warm is the stuff that runs OUTSIDE the lambda handler. The EF Core query only occurs within my handler, e.g. within my:

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponse PostCustomerProxyResponse(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
```

I believe that the only code that gets kept 'warm' by provisioned concurrency, is what occurs in the constructor, e.g.

```
public Functions()
{
    _jSchema = new JSchemaGenerator().Generate(typeof(CustomerPayload));
    _systemsManagementClient = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

    SecurityKey = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + Integration + JWT + "/secret", true);
    Issuer = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + Integration + JWT + "/issuer", false);
    ClaimName = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + Integration + JWT + "/claim", false);
    ScpiUser = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + Integration + SCPI + "/user", false);
    ScpiPassword = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + Integration + SCPI + "/password", true);
    //DbUser = PopulateParameter(ParameterPath + ParameterPathDatabase + "/iamuser", false);
}
```

I tried to add a small database query to the constructor, basically a call to ExecuteRawSQL() in Entity Framework to 'SELECT 1' from PostgreSQL, in the hopes that would count as that first query, and my actual API invocation would be faster, but this failed miserably. The entire API actually times out when trying to invoke the method if I have this 'SELECT 1' code in the Lambda constructor.

I'm at a loss. Can anyone assist? I am at the point of dumping EF Core and going back to a simple query engine like SqlKata which would be a shame, as the mappings and entities within EF Core make it great to work with.  If it helps, I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL for my EF Core connection.

Comment: What if you run the query, deploy new version of lambda straightaway (which guarantees a cold start) and run it again? is the second one still slow or fast? if it is fast, then the issue is not EF but rather Postrgres keeping your execution plans warm. As the query is not variable on the input data based on your code

Comment: Hi zaitsman, if I deploy a new version of Lambda, the same results apply. First query is up to 29 seconds, the second one invoked straight after that comes back is super fast. What does this implicate? And how might I attack that problem?

Comment: I should also clarify that further on in the same function there are variable queries based on the customer data incoming (e.g checking if the first name and last name already exist in the database) not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: And if you connect to your db and just run the query, how long does that take to execute? I am just trying to verify you confirmed that the execution time is specifically isolated to EF Core and is not impacted by the amount of data, complexity of query etc. etc.

Comment: Run directly against the DB:  Rows selected. in 30 ms

Comment: I should also point out that this method ends in a SaveChanges() to save the incoming JSON to the database.

Comment: Does the hung happen the first time your program sends a query to AWS or it only happens after you have issued some queries and idled for a time?

Comment: Gusman, it happens in both instances.

Comment: I think you are seeing the overhead of EF building it's in-memory representation of your data model - as you mention a lighter weight framework is probably a better fit for Lambda (Dapper is always my first choice)

Comment: Thanks Stewart. I am getting a lot of value out of EF because I described my relationships between tables etc well at the beginning, so I'm hoping there are ways I can improve that in-memory representation? E.g. is there a way to call or setup the context better for a Lambda scenario? Configuration changes? I have actually gotten that latency down quite a lot by raising the memory limit for the Lambda containers, but being such a beginner I'm sure there's EF Core things I don't know about that could help maybe?

Comment: Since you're connecting to RDS you've probably got an NIC to attach (yes this is part of cold start, but) the latency you experience seems to occur as soon as your lambda connects to the outside world or VPC. Can you replicate the latency by opening a simple socket connection to RDS or another system? Another thing jumping to mind is perhaps a slow DNS resolver or suboptimal routing configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this exact issue (hence bringing me here).
My lambda was only allocated 128MB and was taking 17 seconds to build up EF.
On upping the memory to 2048MB, the same process was reduced to 1 second.
The lambda actually only required 168 MB but of course, that's more than the original 128MB.

Comment: But why only the first call is slow? If I run the lambda again, it runs fast. It's slow for me even if I don't make a call to the db. This can take more than 10 seconds: _context.Users.FromSqlRaw("select * from User")

Answer (score 0):

please try this...

```
var dupeEmailCustomers = ( from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
                        join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
                        where cu.Status == Customer.CustomerStates.Active
                                && c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
                        select c
                        ).AsNoTracking()
                    .Union(
                        from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
                        join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
                        where c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
                               && cu.Status != Customer.CustomerStates.Active 
                               && testArray.Contains(cu.StatusReason)
                        select c
                        ).AsNoTracking();
```

test the timing on these seperately

```
    from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
    join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
    where cu.Status == Customer.CustomerStates.Active
            && c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
    select c
```

and

```
    from c in loyalty.ContactInformation
    join cu in loyalty.Customer on c.CustomerInternalId equals cu.CustomerInternalId
    where c.ContactType == "EMAIL"
           && cu.Status != Customer.CustomerStates.Active 
           && testArray.Contains(cu.StatusReason)
    select c
```

you could be missing index.... try add index on ContactType and Status and check out if you need one on StatusReason

Comment: also please indicate how many records you are working with... may make sense to just fetch all (contactType="Email") and filter in mem,

Comment: AWS Lambda Functions may have memory limits and depending on how many records you are working with this may have an impact. Functions like this are more for working with very small volumes but scaled horizontally.

Comment: only read after but as you can see my above comment  also leaning towards @Stewart Ritchie  comment, u are probably reaching mem limits of functions, check by timing locally and gettting an idea of how many records you are working with. indexs will help with raw seek time but if you problem is memory that wont help